# Mapping array items into dropdown filters error - Gatsby

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, graphql, filtering

I am trying to map some array items into filter drop-downs to sort the array output. However, i'm getting an error - 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodes' of undefined'. The graphQL query is correct as in runs fine in graphiql, the console log also shows the data coming through.

Any pointers on whats going on & what I need to change would be great. Please let me know if you need any more info. -

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from "react";
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'

const Page = ({data}) => {
  console.log('data is', data)
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
   type: "",
   propertyStatus: ""
 });

  const filteredProperties = data.allStrapiHomes.nodes.filter((node) =>
    Object.entries(filters).every(([filterName, filterValue]) => {
      if (filterValue === "") {
        return true;
      }

      return node[filterName] === filterValue;
    }),
  );

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {Object.entries(filters).map(([filterName, filterValue]) => {
        const allValuesForFilterKey = data.allStrapiHomes.nodes.map(
          (node) => node[filterName],
        );
        const uniqueValuesForFilterKey = [...new Set(allValuesForFilterKey)];

        return (
          <label style={{ marginRight: 10 }}>
            <span style={{ marginRight: 5 }}>{filterName}:</span>
            <select
              value={filterValue}
              onChange={(event) => {
                event.persist();
                setFilters((previousFilters) => {
                  return {
                    ...previousFilters,
                    [filterName]: event.target.value,
                  };
                })
              }                
             }
            >
              <option value="">No filter</option>
              {uniqueValuesForFilterKey.map((value) => (
                <option value={value}>{value}</option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </label>
        );
      })}

      <ul>
        {filteredProperties.map((node) => (
          <li>
            {node.name}
            <br />
            type: {node.type}
            <br />
            category: {node.category}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export const query = graphql`
  query yourQueryName{
      allStrapiHomes {
        nodes {
          type
          propertyStatus
        }
      }
  }
`

export default Page
```

The console log output is this

[image]

Comment: What does `console.log('data is', data)` log?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/pZZ5p0z

Comment: So it would appear your `data` object does not in-fact have a `allStrapiHomes` key which is what your error message says as well

Comment: Replace all `data.allStrapiHomes` calls with `data.edges` and see if that works?

Comment: Aha, looks like it worked, thanks! I now get a similar but different error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined. Is it worth a new post?